# flutter : connection failed mqtt broker

Tags: flutter, ssl, mqtt

i'm using Naver IoT Core.
I am trying to connect to the MQTT broker using the certificate provided by Naver.
But I can't access it.

```
Future connect() async{

　 final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
　 final rootCA = await rootBundle.load('key/rootCaCert.pem');
　 final fullChain = await rootBundle.load('key/fullCertChain.pem');
　 final privateKey = await rootBundle.load('key/06d53a.private.pem');

　 context.setClientAuthoritiesBytes(rootCA.buffer.asUint8List());
　 context.useCertificateChainBytes(fullChain.buffer.asUint8List());
　 context.usePrivateKeyBytes(privateKey.buffer.asUint8List());

　 client.securityContext = context;
　 client.secure = true;
　 // client.setProtocolV31();
　 // client.port = 8883;
　 client.logging(on: true);
　 client.onConnected = onConnected;
　 client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
　 // client.onUnsubscribed = onUnsubscribed;
　 client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
　 client.onSubscribeFail = onSubscribeFail;
　 client.pongCallback = pong;
　 client.autoReconnect = false;
　 print('mqtt init done');
　 try {
　　 print('try');
　　 await client.connect();
　 } catch (e) {
　　print('Exception: $e');
　　 client.disconnect();
　 }
　}
```

RESULT----------------------------------------------------------------

```
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.112228 -- MqttClient::connect - keep alive is disabled
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.128454 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::connect - server msg01.cloudiot.ntruss.com, port 8883
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.132994 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect entered
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.133512 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 0, auto reconnect in progress false
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.134688 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - secure selected
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.136003 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.137806 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - entered
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.300101 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onError - calling disconnected callback
I/flutter ( 6911): Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
I/flutter ( 6911): CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:393))
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.306955 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::disconnect - entered
I/flutter ( 6911): 1-2022-03-17 06:32:58.307622 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
```

Why does Exception occur?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a self signed certificate, which is not trusted by the OS. You can set it as trusted following these steps:

Create a class that overrides `HttpOverrides` in the following way:

```scala
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
            //add your certificate verification logic here
            return true;
          };
  }
}
```

Then, in your main method, instance your class and set it as the global HttpOverride:

```
HttpOverrides.global = new DevHttpOverrides();
```

If `badCertificateCallback` returns `true` it will accept all bad certificates; if returns false it will reject a bad certificate.